# unable to install MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora, mysql-workbench, mysql-gui-tools

When I try to install [MySql Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) using the yum command :

```
yum install mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686.rpm
```

I get these errors :

```
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
       Requires: /bin/python
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
       Requires: libzip.so.2
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
       Requires: libctemplate.so.2
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

*What are these errors and what do I do to install this `MySql` GUI tool ?*

Comment: It means some of the dependencies are missing. (Although it's a bit weird that *python* is missing). You should check if /bin/python, /usr/lib/libzip.so.2 and so on are present on your system. And also if your system is indeed 32bit; check `uname -m`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are installing `RedHat 6` OS base RPM. You have to upgrade or install required dependencies first.  In your case upgrade/install `python` `libzip` `ctemplate` RPM packages.

Notes: `libzip/ctemplate` isn't part of RedHat 6 OS. You have to download from third party sources.